# Understanding a comparison between 'protected virtuals' and 'public virtuals'

Tags: c++

The question is from C++ faq.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/protected-virtuals.html

Code using public overloaded virtuals:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void f(int x);    ← may or may not be pure virtual
  virtual void f(double x); ← may or may not be pure virtual
};
```

Improving this via the Public Overloaded Non-Virtuals Call Protected Non-Overloaded Virtuals idiom:

```
class Base {
public:
  void f(int x)    { f_int(x); }  ← non-virtual
  void f(double x) { f_dbl(x); }  ← non-virtual
protected:
  virtual void f_int(int);
  virtual void f_dbl(double);
};
```

The author said:

> The idea of the Public Overloaded Non-Virtuals Call Protected Non-Overloaded Virtuals idiom is to change the public overloaded methods to non-virtuals, and make those call protected non-overloaded virtuals.

But I do not understand what the author said on how this idiom improve risk:

> the idiom packs the complexity of properly managing the hiding rule into the base class (singular). This means the derived classes (plural) more-or-less automatically handle the hiding rule, so the various developers who produce those derived classes can remain almost completely focused on the details of the derived classes themselves — they need not concern themselves with the (subtle and often misunderstood) hiding rule. This greatly reduces the chance that the writers of the derived classes will screw up the hiding-rule.

Why does this solve the hiding problem? From what I understand, name hiding has nothing to do whether the member function is 'virtual' or not. If a derived class of 'base' rewrites a function f(), it will still hide the f(int) and f(double), right?

From this idiom all I can see is that author change the 'base' virtual f() to non virtual, and put helper functions f_int(), f_dbl() in 'protected virtual', like the name of idiom said. It does nothing good yet but in contrary eliminates possibility of dynamic binding from base class pointer/reference. What is the true benefit of this idiom?

### Update

Kerrek, are you saying this? I do not fully understand the second paragraph of your answer. Could you give an example?

```
class base {
public: 
    virtual void f(int x);
    virtual void f(double x);
}

class derived : public base {
public:
    virtual int f(int x); // oops, will hide base::f(int x) AND base::f(double x)
}

base *bp = new base();
base *dp = new derived();
bp->f(int i);    // ok
dp->f(int i);    // surprise!
dp->f(double d); // compile error!


class Base {
public:
    void f(int x)    { f_int(x); }  
    void f(double x) { f_dbl(x); } 
protected:
    virtual void f_int(int);
    virtual void f_dbl(double);
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    // nothing to override here 'cause f() is non virtual
protected:
    // because f_int() and f_dbl are unique names, override or hide f_int() will not affect f_dbl()?
    virtual int f_int(int);  // oops, will hide base::f(int x), but developer may want this on purpose
                             // no effect on f_dbl(), which is good
}

base bobj;
derived dobj;
bobj.f(int i);    // ok
dobj.f(double d); // ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a derived class declares `void f(int)`, then it *overrides* the virtual function, and the `virtual` specifier is implied. If a derived class declares `int f(int)`, it *hides* the base function. I gather that you're familiar with this.

The problem comes when you want others to develop code based on your base class. With the naive approach, each derived class must be careful to add the correct override so as not to accidentally hide the function and get a working, but wrong program (i.e. the user says `f()` but gets the wrong thing). With the "public non-virtual" idiom, the user always calls `f()` in confidence, and the library developer can override only those parts that she's interested in by overriding a uniquely named, protected function, without having to touch a name that may affect *other* users.

Comment: There is also another reason for the non-virtual public functions, namely that they can centralize checking of pre- and post-conditions, logging, and other general stuff. However, I do not find these reasons compelling. There is a trade-off, namely the complexity of having these different functions, and any problem with overload resolution is likely to and *should* surface via testing -- possibly the programmer's own quick checking of the functionality.

Comment: On a slightly different note, the FAQ's advice to have virtuals `protected` instead of `private` made good sense for C++03, because to the extent that you could assert that a function was an override, it required the base class' declaration to be accessible in the derived class. However, with C++11 we finally have a standard `override` specification. And it works also for `private` virtuals.

Comment: @Alf It also depends on where you learned programming by contract.  The reference here is Bertrand Meyer and the Eiffel programming language.  And in those, a function in a derived class could call a function in the base class without pre- and post-condition checking.  (IMHO, if a base class function provides part of the implementation, it should have a different name from the virtual function, and I've always made my virtual functions private.)

Comment: Kerrek, what do you mean 'With the "public non-virtual" idiom, the user always calls f() in confidence, '? 'in confidence' meaning in secret? i still can not see it. An example?

Comment: Thanks Kerrek. So now i understand that this idiom is to discourage developer from touching f() directly in the derived class, but alway change f_int() and f_dbl() in the derived class to achieve the goal. 'cause otherwise overriding visual in derived class alway has the risk of hiding Base::f if developer is not careful enough. Am i right?

Comment: @user1559625: Yes, sounds right. With the private (or protected) implementation, clients can't call the implementation directly, so you're much less constrained when it comes to refactoring, and because each actual implementation has a unique name, the implementor doesn't need to worry about accidental hiding.

Answer (score 0):

All i can see is that it would reduce the likeliness that you're linking to `SomeDerived::f()` rather than using the virtual `Base::f()`, although I don't remember I've caught a compiler guilty of this so far. Looking for someone else to propose a better answer ...

Answer (score 0):

The main motivation, historically at least, for using non-public virtual
functions has been to support programming by contract.  The
(non-virtual) public functions in `Base` define a contract, with
`assert` (or something similar) of pre- and post-conditions and
invariants.  They forward to private or protected virtual functions for
the actual work.  Thus, for example, the classical `clone` function 
might be defined:

```
class Base
{
    virtual Base* doClone() const = 0;
public:
    Base* clone() const
    {
        Base* results = doClone();
        assert( typeid(*this) == typeid( *results ) );
        return results;
    }
};
```

In the case of `clone`, this sort of protection is probably overkill;
I've yet to see any problems due to a derived class misimplementing it
(or failing to implement it, if there are multiple levels of
derivation).  For most other functions, however, it's a powerful and
effective means of developing robust software.

If you have overloaded functions in the interface, *and* they have
different implementations, I don't see any real reason not to overload
the virtual functions.